# Does Tizen support freely distributed work?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I have looked at their FAQ, docs, and other SO posts, but none are on installing apps.

I'm aware you need to sign your package with author and distro key, but I do not know if you are forced to go through any system.

I miss the good ol' days with SourceForge, if you can't find an app on the shelves, go there, download it, unzip and you're done.

I'm fine with paying for stuff, but my severe hope is that Tizen or another linux phone will allow us to distribute our apps more freely. In fact, the simple ability to reinstall an app is something I miss, badly. Corrupt data, bad saves, whatever, you're screwed - unless something free-to-modify comes along.

Is Tizen the manifestation of this hope, or are we just bound to another store?

Thanks.

Comment: "Save us Obi wan Kanobi, you're our only hope!" - had to resist typing that, but this is a comment... so eh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure SO is the right place for this type of discussions.

In my personal opinion Tizen like other popular platforms tries to give users the feeling that the software they are installing is safe and keeps a certain quality.
Having a store is some kind of assurance that the platform and it's applications are ready for public use and also gives a good chance for small developers who have small budget to go big only by making great code and not pumping money into commercials.

**But...**

To answer your question.
Tizen web applications are `.wgt` files that you install/uninstall on the device.
Creation of those is easy with tools from Tizen SDK.

For installation you may use SDB (thanks @Konrad) or just copy the package onto the device and later install by browsing and opening it through the file system (similar to `.apk`s on Android).

Comment: Cool! I'm glad this topic is seeing some activity. wgt looks familiar, I'm not a linux geek though, is that similar to an easy package manager? Either way, it looks like Tizen apps will finally be open, and allow the freedom that many people don't seem to know they've missed out on since about 2007 ish (app store begins)

Answer (score 2):

Tizen is open source - you can take it and change it as you like :)
Beside that there is SDB tool that you can use to

```
sdb install
sdb uninstall
```

What more do you need?

Comment: I hope that's the case. Android forces you to compile to a JRE that nobody else uses, otherwise it'd be awesome. Tizen has a store, you have to sign your app and upload it there, but I'm betting one can go to a website, click on an install file, and be done. 

Apple still won't let me go past the mailboxes, otherwise I'd have a comparison for you :D. I'm just asking if Tizen will force signage and distro-locks. I would very much enjoy installing a real QT app from sourceForge if possible, just for kicks. Running real linux Apps, compiling C++, levelling the playing field, not bound to any corp